# awk print the last row of file failed

Tags: shell, awk

```
$cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

I want to print the value of last row.

```
$awk '{print $NR}' file
1
```

Why the output is not 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike sed, awk does not have a way to specify the last line.  A work-around is:

```
$ awk '{line=$0} END{print line}' file
0
```

#### Discussion

Let's look at your command at see what it actually does.  Consider this test file:

```
$ cat testfile
a b  c
A B  C
i ii iii
```

Now, let's run your command:

```
$ awk '{print $NR}' testfile
a
B
iii
```

As you can see, `print $NR` prints the diagonal.  In other words, on line number `NR`, it prints field number `NR`.  So, on the first line, `NR=1`, the command `print $NR` prints the first field.  On the second line, `NR=2`, the command `print $NR` prints the second field.  And so on.

Comment: it is great, I see.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code, which will print the last line of any Input_file. Here `END` section is the out of the box `awk` keyword which is used to execute the commands/statements after main section. So I am simply printing the line in END section which will print the last line.

```
awk 'END{print $0}'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'END{print}'  Input_file
```